# Is the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ ? Justify

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ ? Justify.

From intuition I believe it is Lebesgue integrable, since it is Riemann integrable. $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\int_0^1 x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=2x^{\frac{1}{2}}\vert_0^1=2$$Also by then fact that the points of discontinuities is countable i.e$( x=o)$.
Is there any formal way to show this results preferably by constructing simple function approximation of $f(x)$?
Any help? thank you

Comment: Monotone convergence comes in handy here if you consider $\chi_{[\frac 1n, 1]}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$

Comment: Okay, thank you. So by how  I understand your idea, let me put something down so that you tell me whether I'm cutting close.

Comment: That is $\rho_n(x)=\chi_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$
.
I see that $\rho_n(x)\le \rho_{n+1}(x)$ and also $\rho_n(x)\le f(x) \forall n$.
Can I say the following/ as $n \rightarrow \infty, \rho_n(x) \xrightarrow{?} f(x)$
And also from the definition of lebesgue integral of a positive function $f$
$$\int  fdm=sup\{\int\rho dm, where \quad o\le \rho\le f$$.

so $$sup \int_{[\frac{1}{n},1]}\rho dm =\int_{(o,1]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=2 $$

I know there are a lot of errors in there. I may refine it if I am on the right path.